# Find All Mondays Of Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm  trying to find all mondays of years in plsql

```
SELECT TO_DATE(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')||'0101','YYYYMMDD') + 7 * (level-(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'WW')-1)-2)+3) first_day_week 
FROM dual
connect by level <= 365;
```

I tried to this but didnt work and couldnt figured out. Also I dont want to use

```
  select 
   next_day ( sysdate, 'monday' )+1 + ( ( level -1 ) * 7 ) mondays
  from   dual
```

this expression because of language settings

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Comment: Your instinct to avoid dependence on language is correct. But that doesn't mean you have to sacrifice the efficiency of the "second approach". As WD demonstrates in his answer, you can "save" that approach - you don't need to generate ALL the dates of the year, just to keep the Mondays. That is a very inefficient (and ugly) way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be independent from any NLS Settings I would suggest this one:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')+6, 'IW') + (LEVEL-1)*7
FROM dual
CONNECT BY TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')+6, 'IW') + (LEVEL-1)*7 < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 12);
```

Comment: A brief explanation of the algorithm would help. Something along the lines of `trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy')` returns January 1 of the current year. Then we add 6 (days), so we get January 7; and then we truncate to the beginning of the ISO week, meaning to the Monday preceding (or equal to) January 7. And that's the whole point: the first Monday of any year is **always** the Monday of the (ISO) week that includes January 7. This explains the "magic number" 6 used in the formula. The rest is standard code, but this explanation of the overall "magic formula" may not be entirely obvious.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much everybody! I also used

select TRUNC(sysdate, 'DAY')+(level-1)*7 start_of_the_week
from dual
connect by level <365

this query and worked

Comment: And that query returned Mondays? Unless you ran it on a Monday, that wouldn't be possible. Also, it would generate 365 different days (Mondays or whatever), one week apart - are you sure all your results were in the same year? (I am 100% sure they weren't). This is definitely NOT a helpful answer.